# POSTGRES: How to select rows with a certain value only if another value doesn't exist, and in that case select the other value?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Here is an example of the table I am working with. What I would like to achieve is to select the most recent row where the type is not 'NONE' unless 'NONE' is the only type available for that id.

| id | date | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 01-01-2021 | NONE |
| 123 | 12-31-2021 | NONE |
| 123 | 01-01-2021 | METAL |
| 123 | 12-31-2021 | METAL |

From the example table above I would expect the query to return this

| id | date | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 12-31-2021 | METAL |

If the table were to only contain types of "NONE" such as this example...

| id | date | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 01-01-2021 | NONE |
| 123 | 12-31-2021 | NONE |
| 123 | 01-01-2021 | NONE |
| 123 | 12-31-2021 | NONE |

Then I would expect the result set to be..

| id | date | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 12-31-2021 | NONE |

I've tried a plethora of different ways to do this but my current attempt looked something like this. It works when there's only one ID in the table but not for when I try to select a row for every specific ID in the table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id),
       date,
       type
FROM 
    example_table
WHERE
    CASE
        WHEN 
            (   SELECT 
                    COUNT(*) 
                FROM 
                    example_table t 
                WHERE 
                    t.type <> 'NONE'
                AND t.id = example_table.id) 
            <> 0
        THEN type <> 'NONE'
        ELSE 1=1
    END
ORDER BY 
    id, date DESC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Row_number() function together with a case statement to identify which row to pick.

```
with cte AS
(
  select id,
       date, 
       type,
       row_number() over(partition by id 
                          order by case when type <> 'NONE' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, date desc
                          ) as RN
       
  from test
 )
 select *
 from cte
 where rn = 1
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/4f44b3/5)

Comment: Thank you I like this. I would appreciate it if you could help me understand how that case statement works, specifically the THEN 1 ELSE 2 part in the order by clause. order by 1 order by 2? What is that doing?

Comment: Using the case statement, you are basically assigning weight to the types and then use the weight to order them.

Comment: You are assigning smaller number to the values other than 'None' so that they will come first when you order them.

Comment: Aha thanks. I was never aware you could use order by and assign weights like that.

Answer (score 1):

Without using Analytical function:
SQL:

```
with cte
as
(
 select id,type,flag, max(date) date from (select id , date , type, case when type='NONE' then 'flag_none' else 'flag_not_none' end as flag from test) x group by  id,type,flag)
select id,type,date from cte where flag='flag_not_none'  and  (id,date) in (select id,max(date) from cte group by id)
union
select id,type,date from cte where id not in (select id from cte where flag='flag_not_none'  and  (id,date) in (select id,max(date) from cte group by id)) and flag='flag_none';
```

Full Execution:

```
CREATE TABLE test 
(

  id int,
  date date,
  type text
);

insert into test
values
(123,  '01-01-2021', 'NONE'),
(123, '12-31-2021', 'NONE'),
(123, '01-01-2021', 'METAL'),
(123, '12-31-2021', 'PLASTIC'),
(124,  '01-01-2021', 'NONE'),
(124, '12-31-2021', 'NONE'),
(124, '01-01-2021', 'NONE'),
(124, '12-31-2021', 'NONE'),
(125, '12-25-2021', 'NONE'),
(125, '12-25-2021', 'RUBBER'),
(125, '12-31-2021', 'STEEL');

postgres=# with cte
postgres-# as
postgres-# (
postgres(#  select id,type,flag, max(date) date from (select id , date , type, case when type='NONE' then 'flag_none' else 'flag_not_none' end as flag from test) x group by  id,type,flag)
postgres-# select id,type,date from cte where flag='flag_not_none'  and  (id,date) in (select id,max(date) from cte group by id)
postgres-# union
postgres-# select id,type,date from cte where id not in (select id from cte where flag='flag_not_none'  and  (id,date) in (select id,max(date) from cte group by id)) and flag='flag_none';
 id  |  type   |    date
-----+---------+------------
 123 | PLASTIC | 2021-12-31
 124 | NONE    | 2021-12-31
 125 | STEEL   | 2021-12-31
(3 rows)
```